# ARM Assembly, Keil Microvision 4; Working with non-zero registry values

Tags: arm

Hoping for just a bit of help with something.

I have a college assignment which involves making what is basically a calculator that takes values entered in by the user as a string of ASCII characters and stores and displays the entered value, as well as making various computations such as sum, min, etc. and stores them all as well. The code only executes after a value is entered.

My code itself is working how I need it to so far, and I think I know how to write in all the computations, but my issue is that most of the registers hold non-zero values from the start, and so if I start adding in values to a register right away -- for the sum, for instance -- the end value will be incorrect. I can't just use LDR and set them to zero beforehand, though, since that will happen every time the code is run, and I need to keep the added values around to make the computations each time.

I don't know if I'm overthinking this or if there's something really simple that I'm missing, but I can't think of a way to do what I need to with non-zero registry values.

This is my working code so far:

```
AREA    ConsoleInput, CODE, READONLY
IMPORT  main
IMPORT  getkey
IMPORT  sendchar
EXPORT  start
PRESERVE8

start

read

LDR R7, =0

BL  getkey      ; read key from console

CMP R0, #0x0D   ; while (key != CR)

BEQ endRead     ; {

BL  sendchar    ;   echo key back to console

;R4 is used to store the hex value of whatever is entered (as a full number)
;R5 stored the entered input safely (as R0 can change)
;R6 holds the constant 10, for increasing successive entries by a base of ten
;R10 is where successive values are multiplied by 10
;R11 is used to hold the count (+1 each time the code is run)


LDR R6, =10
MUL R10, R6, R10
MOV R5, R0
AND R5, R5, #&F
ADD R10, R10, R5
MOV R4, R10 ;NUMBER ENTERED SENT TO R4

ADD R11, R11, #1    ;COUNT




B   read        ; }

endRead

stop    B   stop

END
```